# Как осуществляется привязка товара на сайте под БУС к товару внутри 1С?

Tags: битрикс, 1с, commerceml

Какие внутренние механизмы 1С сопоставляют конкретный товар с сайта с конкретной записью в 1С?
Ведется ли это в CommerceML как отдельный словарь `ID на сайте -> ID внутри 1С` или ещё каким-нибудь способом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Связка товаров осуществляется по `GUID` элемента в 1С и `Внешнего кода` на сайте. Для свойств и их значение используется соответственно `GUID` свойства и `GUID` значения свойства, которые на сайте видны как `XML_ID` в таблице свойств инфоблока. Построение xml-файлов модулями обмена основано на создании файлов описывающих структуры, где ключевым/основным элементам и их потомках прописываются `GUID, а затем уже в общем списке товаров вместо значений подставляются именно`GUID`ы. Обработка на сайте/обновление/считывание файла загруженного 1Ской идет по этим самым`GUID`ам.

Answer (score 0):

Передаётся артикул из 1с и сохраняется в товаре как поле XML_ID. По этому полю идентифицируются товары.

Comment: Не по артикулу, а по GUID. Это ИД записи в таблице с которой работает 1С.